# Call function from a class in C#

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm using `CefSharp` as Graphical Interface and I want to close the window when the user presses the button 'close'. Now I have to call the function `close();` from the function `exit();`, that's inside of the class `CallbackObjectForJs`. How can I do it?

```
ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
public void close()
{
    this.Close();
}
private void form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.myurl.com");
    browser.RegisterJsObject("csalert", new CallbackObjectForJs());
    this.Controls.Add(browser);
}
public class CallbackObjectForJs{
    public void alert(string msg){
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
    public void exit() {
        close(); //that not works
    }
}
```

Comment: If ```close()``` is function, shouldn't it in any class or struct ?

Comment: If you want to directly access it, just add it in ```static``` class, you will access it by its class name

Comment: If you are using `WinForms` (please edit your tags if you are), you can just call `window.close` in javascript and the form will close https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `close` directly, but you can use a little trick, pass instance be the construct method from `CallbackObjectForJs`

```
ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
public void close()
{
    this.Close();
}
private void form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.myurl.com");
    browser.RegisterJsObject("csalert", new CallbackObjectForJs(this));
    this.Controls.Add(browser);
}

public class CallbackObjectForJs{

    Form _form;

    public CallbackObjectForJs(Form form){

        _form = form;
    }

    public void alert(string msg){
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
    public void exit() {
        _form.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns me "Exception of "System.InvalidOperationException" type in unmanaged System.Windows.Forms.dll in user code", may be because this window is a dialog

Comment: You will need to `Invoke` the call back onto the `UI Thread` as you can only access the `Form` from the `UI Thread`.